# Is there a way to register a desktop application as a handler for a custom URL protocol, such that all browsers will honour it?

Tags: linux, url, browser, desktop-application

It looks like Chrome uses xdg-open, so it's sufficient to create a .desktop file for you application and register it via mimeapps.list.

Firefox doesn't appear to honour this. I also tried registering via gconftool as suggested at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#All_Firefox_versions, but Firefox still doesn't seem to recognise the protocol, and entering "myprotocol://foo" just triggers a search rather than launching my application.

Is there a foolproof way to do this on all Linux versions which supports all  browsers? Or at least a list of common bases to cover which will work for the majority of distro/browser combinations?

Note: this must be do-able programmatically - I want the application to register itself

Comment: I created a .desktop file and added it to mimeapps.list and Firefox honors it. Maybe they fixed this issue in the Quantum rewrite?